# why covering dim of $n$-dimensional simplicial complex is at most $n$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm self-studying "Elements of Algebraic Topology" by Munkres these days.

In that book, Exercise #2 (d) in section 15 asks you to prove the following

**If $K$ is $n$-dimensional finite simplicial complex, (Lebesgue) covering dimension of $\vert K\vert$ is at most $n$.**

I can prove that covering dimension of $n$-dimensional simplex is at most $n$. That is easy because you can think $n$-dimensional simplex as closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, I don't know how to approach to prove the simplicial *complex* case. Some clever gluing is necessary, maybe?

And here is follow-up question. In section 16, Exercise #3 asks you to show that **any $n$-dimensional simplicial complex has at most $n$ covering dimension**. So, number of simplexes in $K$ doesn't need to be finite in this more general problem.

I'm looking for hints or solutions to prove above two exercises. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can cover the finite $n$-dimensional complex by finitely many ${≤}n$-dimensional simplices.

Comment: There is the closed sum theorem in dimension theory that implies this. If you're allowed to use dimension theory...

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Even though I hope to see elementary proof as possible, I want to see the ideas from the sum theorem. Do you have any suggestion for dimension theory reference?

Comment: Engelking's book on dimension theory is good, but quite "heavy" from trying to be as general as possible. Van Mill's book on infinite dimensional topology have a relatively short and self contained intro.

Comment: My try for a  finite n-simplicial complex in $R^N$: given an open covering, make successive barycentric divisions, until the diameter of each simplex is small enough (see [Lebesgue's covering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue's_number_lemma)). Now take a small neighborhood of each n-simplex, so that every point lies in no more than $n+1$ neighborhoods. I hope you can make this argument formal. Good luck!